# iPad Swift Playgrounds shares blank .playgrounds file

Tags: ios, swift

I have started a beginning Swift programming class, which is going well so far, but I do not have access to a Mac for Xcode. I do have Swift Playgrounds for iPad, which allows me to complete the assignments and test that they work, but when I try to share the .playground file, it exports a blank file. Is there a solution for this problem?

Failing that, is there a way to save a text file containing Swift code as a .playground file on a PC? Buying a Mac (even a used one) is not an option at the moment, and using the on-campus computer lab takes over 3 hours round trip, so even a very convoluted workaround would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You can share the playground from the iOS app to Working Copy, an iOS Git client.

`Save in Working Copy > Save as .playground dir`

It's free to try and you can export the repository as a zip file. So you can save it to Dropbox, or e-mail it to yourself. If you get the paid version, or in-app purchase, you can push it up to Github, or Bitbucket, which would make it easier to share any changes back. Working Copy can be added to the list of locations you can import Playgrounds from so that would probably be a worthwhile investment.

The enterprise version is the same price as the in-app purchase on the free app and includes the features the in-app unlocks.

Working Copy - Powerful Git client by Anders Borum
https://appsto.re/gb/xONC1.i

Working Copy Enterprise by Anders Borum
https://appsto.re/gb/aEqH5.i

In testing the exporting of a zip file I found the Dropbox support a little glitchy. I had more luck doing 'Import to Evernote' which created a *-playground.zip in Evernote. I could then save that to Dropbox. I've not had a chance to confirm the e-mailed version but it looks okay.

Pushing the .playground up to Github works just fine.